# gemfire start server --spring-xml-location parameter giving class not found for org....SpringContextBootstrappingInitializer

Tags: java, spring, gemfile

Hi I'm trying to bootstrap a spring context inside gemfire and also starting gemfire server from gfsh. My scripts look like:

```
start locator --name=locator1 --J=-Dgemfire.OSProcess.ENABLE_OUTPUT_REDIRECTION=true
configure pdx --auto-serializable-classes=demo.domain.*
configure pdx --read-serialized=true
start server --name=server1 --J=-Dgemfire.OSProcess.ENABLE_OUTPUT_REDIRECTION=true
deploy --jar=domain-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
stop server --name=server1
start server --name=server1 --J=-Dgemfire.OSProcess.ENABLE_OUTPUT_REDIRECTION=true --spring-xml-location=spring-config.xml
```

But here I'm getting a `ClassNotFoundException`. The stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/gemfire/support/SpringContextBootstrappingInitializer
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.ServerLauncher.startWithSpring(ServerLauncher.java:764)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.ServerLauncher.start(ServerLauncher.java:696)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.ServerLauncher.run(ServerLauncher.java:626)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.ServerLauncher.main(ServerLauncher.java:200)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.gemfire.support.SpringContextBootstrappingInitializer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 4 more
```

Can anyone help me find what mistake I made? Maybe I need to add few classes to the classpath, can anyone tell me which are those classes and how can I add all those jars.
--Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems this question is not getting any attention.